# jquery kendo grid I need to get selected rows dataitems array even i paginate pagination serverside true

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using jquery kendo grid Kendo UI v2019.2.514

```
serverPaging: true,
serverSorting: true,
serverFiltering: true,
pageSize: 15
```

Example given below but here there is no server side pagination
https://dojo.telerik.com/UHUKahIM

I need dataItmes of selected rows in on change event or some other event
Ex:- i selected 2 rows in page:1 and page :2 selected 3 rows so totally 5 rows, i need these selected 5 rows dataItems array in array variable.
Please help me on this
I tried like below

```
function onChange(e) {
        var rows = e.sender.select();
        rows.each(function(e) {
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);

            console.log(dataItem);
        })
    };
```

but this is not working for my expectation, this is working only the current page i need all the pages selected records as a array

Answer (score 0):

The DOJO example you posted shows how to get the selected ids between pages, using `this.selectedKeyNames()`. Use that method to get an array of dataItems from the dataSource:

```
function onChange(arg) {
    let selectedIds = this.selectedKeyNames(),
        dataItems = this.dataSource.data().toJSON().filter(dataItem => {
            return selectedIds.indexOf(dataItem.ProductID.toString()) > -1;
        });
      
    console.log(dataItems);
}
```

[Updated DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/UHUKahIM/2)

Note: The property `ProductId` used in the code above must be the same set in the `schema.model.id` parameter:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "ProductID"
    }
}
```

Comment: page:1 i select 2 record, dataItems shown 2 items fine, i am navigate to 2nd page i select   one record here dataItems shown/printing only 1 item its not fine, here need to print 3 items,I am using serverside pagination.

Comment: Hi Please help me on this.

Comment: @raj Use a global array then.